# How we generate CheckSum and Open Paytm

Tags: ios, objective-c, paytm

I want to Use Payment Gateway with Paytm.First I am unable to generate CHECKSUMHASH . Then if I am hardcord. Then it show OOPS page of Paytm.Please Help .Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

```
PGMerchantConfiguration *mc = [PGMerchantConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
mc.checksumGenerationURL = @"http://lucky7.co.in/paytm/generateChecksum.php";
mc.checksumValidationURL = @"http://lucky7.co.in/paytm/verifyChecksum.php";

//Step 2: Create the order with whatever params you want to add. But make sure that you include the merchant mandatory params
NSMutableDictionary *orderDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

//Merchant configuration in the order object
orderDict[@"MID"] = @"SSMENT54168661059890";
orderDict[@"ORDER_ID"] = @"Order000111008";
orderDict[@"CUST_ID"] = @"12";
orderDict[@"INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = @"Retail";
orderDict[@"CHANNEL_ID"] = @"WAP";
orderDict[@"TXN_AMOUNT"] = @"1";
orderDict[@"WEBSITE"] = @"APP_STAGING";
orderDict[@"CALLBACK_URL"] = @"http://lucky7.co.in/paytm/verifyChecksum.php";
orderDict[@"EMAIL"] = @"eee@gmail.com";
orderDict[@"MOBILE_NO"] = @"9996725992";
orderDict[@"REQUEST_TYPE"] = @"DEFAULT";
//    orderDict[@"CHECKSUMHASH"] = @"ohpYnZUoSUqFsQ0uUVArWPnlTdLPSZWhinaCWSGKME5HJzAlZephJuaCFxs5tJbSKViPbrlEsJEIEVIcJARFANm4rN1pk7n4193CBs53Zg=";


PGOrder *order = [PGOrder orderWithParams:orderDict];

//Step 3: Choose the PG server. In your production build dont call selectServerDialog. Just create a instance of the
//PGTransactionViewController and set the serverType to eServerTypeProduction
[PGServerEnvironment selectServerDialog:self.view completionHandler:^(ServerType type)
 {
     PGTransactionViewController *txnController = [[PGTransactionViewController alloc] initTransactionForOrder:order];

        //txnController.merchant = [PGMerchantConfiguration defaultConfiguration];

     if (type != eServerTypeNone) {
         txnController.serverType = type;
         txnController.merchant = mc;
         txnController.delegate = self;
         [self showController:txnController];
     }

}];
```

Comment: http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/discussion/topic/checksumhash/ ?

Comment: checksum can be generated in the backend with the help of paytm checksum generation kit. You need to publish that kit on your webservice